# java date value not showing correctly

Tags: java, date, datetime, calendar, monthcalendar

I am getting following problem, while executing this logic for java date:

```
 String weboutput = "OCT 27 08:20 PM";
 DateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM DD hh:mm a" , Locale.US);
 inputTime = formatter1.parse(weboutput);
 Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(); 
 Calendar today = new GregorianCalendar();
 calendar.setTime(inputTime); 
 int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
 int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
 int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
 System.out.println("\n"+month+"\n");
 int date = calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);
 today.setTime(new Date());
 today.set(Calendar.HOUR, hour);
 today.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
 today.set(Calendar.MONDAY, month);
 today.set(Calendar.DATE, date);
 Date retrivedDate = today.getTime();
 System.out.println(retrivedDate);
```

But it gives me following output :
     Tue Jan 27 20:20:12 IST 2015, there should be Oct instead of Jan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use lower case dd for date

```
DateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd hh:mm a" , Locale.US);
```

DD is the day of the year

dd is day of the month.

For more details see the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: So does it means while I use DD i can give any value till 365 and accordingly month will be selected?

Comment: @PranavNath Yes that is the meaning of day of year

Comment: Thanks Jens for corroboration and bolstering, it was very swift and helpful, will go through java doc document as suggested.